# Ignore trailing slash with Apache Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect like so:

`RewriteRule (work)/?$ $1.php [L]`

This sends any URL ending in `/work` or `/work/` to `work.php`

The problem is, when a trailing slash is included, it treats it as a directory, and not the file that it really is. This, of course, breaks all of my relative paths in the file.

I don't mind having a slash in the URL, but is there any way to use Apache to *ignore* the trailing slash, and treat the URL as a file, just as it would without the slash?

Comment: do you have a "work" directory?

Comment: do you have anything else in the .htaccess or vhost?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you don't want the URL to look like `www.domain.com/work/` here's what you can do:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^work/$ http://www.domain.com/work%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
  RewriteRule (work)$ $1.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will redirect `/work/` to `/work` and `/work/?page=main` to `/work?page=main`